# Go to webinar custom landing page

Tags: php

I using gotowebinar service to register user from custom landing page:
API LINK https://goto-developer.logmeininc.com/
How to create the right flow to register user into webinar?
and how to get organizer_id ??

thanks

here my code.

```
$webinar_id = "336-174-566";

$gtwPost = array(
  "firstName" => $contact_data['FirstName'],
  "lastName"  => $contact_data['LastName'],
  "email" => $contact_data['Email']
);

$gtwHeaders = array( 
    "Accept:application/vnd.citrix.g2wapi-v1.1+json", 
    "Content-Type:application/json", 
    "Authorization:OAuth oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxx"
); 

$this->data['gtw'] = array(
  'post' => $gtwPost,
  'headers' => $gtwHeaders
);

//Set POST URL for GoToWebinar
$gtw_url = "https://api.citrixonline.com/G2W/rest/organizers/".$organizer_id."/webinars/".$webinar_id."/registrants";

//Start GoToWebinar submission
$curl = @curl_init();
@curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($gtwPost));
@curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $gtw_url);
#@curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
@curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
@curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
@curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $gtwHeaders);
@curl_exec($curl);
$info = @curl_getinfo($curl);
@curl_close($curl);
//End GoToWebinar registrant submission
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution here, in git hub 
https://github.com/zakir-hyder/Citrix-GoToWebinar-PHP-Library

you have to create application first, after provide details to the script:

```
$citrix = new Citrix('API Key');
$citrix->set_organizer_key('organizer_key');
$citrix->set_access_token('access_token');
```

code example:

```
<?php
include "citrix.php";
$citrix = new Citrix('API Key');
$citrix->set_organizer_key('organizer_key');
$citrix->set_access_token('access_token');
try
{
    $organizer_key = $citrix->get_organizer_key();
    $citrix->pr($organizer_key);
}catch (Exception $e) { 
    $citrix->pr($e->getMessage());
}
try
{
    $webinars = $citrix->citrixonline_get_list_of_webinars() ;
    $citrix->pr($webinars);
}catch (Exception $e) { 
    $citrix->pr($e->getMessage());
}
try
{
    $response = $citrix->citrixonline_create_registrant_of_webinar('webinar id', $data = array('first_name' => 'First Name', 'last_name' => 'Lastnmae', 'email'=>'email@email.com')) ;
    $citrix->pr($response);
}catch (Exception $e) { 
    $citrix->pr($e->getMessage());
}
try
{
    $webinars = $citrix->get_registrants_of_webinars('webinar id') ;
    $citrix->pr($webinars);
}catch (Exception $e) { 
    $citrix->pr($e->getMessage());
}
try
{
    $citrix->citrixonline_delete_registrant_of_webinar('webinar id', 'registrant id') ;
}catch (Exception $e) { 
    $citrix->pr($e->getMessage());
}
```